# whats the difference between python cv2.imread ,flags cv2.IMREAD_COLOR and CV2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR?

Tags: python, opencv

whats the difference between python cv2.imread ,flags  cv2.IMREAD_COLOR and CV2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR ?

Answer (score 1):

from [docs](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#gga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80af660544735200cbe942eea09232eb822)

IMREAD_COLOR : If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.

IMREAD_ANYCOLOR : If set, the image is read in any possible color format.

So, you may not notice a difference if ANYCOLOR ends up choosing RGB to read.

Comment: example for a different anycolor result can be png images with alpga channel